# Reshape a matrix in matlab with nan elements

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a `Nx3`-matrix in matlab, where I have a degree value from 0 to 360 in the first column, a radius value from 0 to 0.5 in the second and an integer in the third. Every combination out of `(M(n,1),M(n,2))` is unique with `M` the matrix and `n` a random number between 1 and N, but it is possible that there is a value in `M(:,1)` or `M(:,2)` more than once. `M` is sorted, first after the first row, then after the second.

My target is now to reshape this matrix into a `360xV`-matrix, with `V` the amount of unique values in `M(:,2)`. If there is a value in `M(:,3)` at the position `M(o,1)` and `M(p,2)` with `1 <= o, p <= N`, it should be placed at the position `(o,p)`, if there is no value, then there should a `NaN`-value placed instead.

Is there a simple way to do this, or do I have to write my own function for that?

Edit:
Desired input:

```
0 0.25 1  
0 0.43 4  
1 0.25 2  
2 0.03 5  
2 0.43 2
```

Desired output:

```
NaN 1 4  
NaN 2 NaN  
5 NaN 2
```

Comment: Post a small example with input and desired output

Comment: @LuisMendo: Done, I hope this makes things a bit easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an approach of finding `unique indices` for the `first` and `second` columns from the input arrays and then using those to set elements in an *appropriately* (discussed in more detail inside the code as comments) sized output array with the elements from the `third` column. Here's the implementation -

```
%// Input array
A = [
    0 0.25 1
    0 0.43 4
    1 0.25 2
    2 0.03 5
    2 0.43 2 ]

%// Find unique indices for col-1,2
[~,~,idx1] = unique(A(:,1)) %// these would form the row indices of output
[~,~,idx2] = unique(A(:,2)) %// these would form the col indices of output

%// Decide the size of output array based on the "extents" of those indices
nrows = max(idx1)
ncols = max(idx2)

%// Initialize output array with NaNs
out = NaN(nrows,ncols)

%// Set the elements in output indexed by those indices to values from
%// col-3 of input array
out((idx2-1)*nrows + idx1) = A(:,3)
```

Code run -

```
out =
   NaN     1     4
   NaN     2   NaN
     5   NaN     2
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a simple way to do this, or do I have to write my own function for that?

You'll need to write a method, seeing that what you've described is utterly specific to your problem. There's methods to find unique values, so this will help you when designing your `for` loop.